# How can I make the "References" section more than one page long using Bibtex

Tags: biblatex, bibtex, overleaf, thesis

I am using Bibtex for my citations in my thesis. Everything works fine, but the "References/ Bibliography" section at the end of my article is capped at 1 pages long. I have more than 8 references in my .bib file, but there are only 8 to be seen on the References section. What can I do?

To print my bibliography I just use the \printbibliography command.

Thanks!
[image: The bibliography page]
[image: My references file (refs.bib)]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  BibTeX doesn't cap the length by default.  What might be happening is that you're not seeing all of the references because you're not using them in your document.  (But please try to not post images of code when copy/paste is much better.)

Comment: @Teepeemm you are exactly correct, I had no idea and I panicked. (I will keep your comment in mind, thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

OK, turns out you have to first \cite every citation inside the actual text for it to appear in the References section

Cheers!

Comment: Or use `\nocite{*}` to pick up the references that aren't cited individually.